# Change of variables in a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:
$$\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} + \frac{1}{b^{2}} y = -\frac{\pi}{b} J(1, x).$$
$J$ is the Bessel function of first type. In order to be able to solve it exactly (at least according to Mathematica), I need to change the variables so that the two terms on the LHS have equal coefficients. So, I try $x = b t$, and get
$$\frac{1}{b^{2}}\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}} + \frac{1}{b^{2}} y = -\frac{\pi}{b} J(1, bt)$$
Is this correct? Is this how I change variables in a differential equation, especially in the inhomogeneous term? When I find a solution, what variable is it in exactly? How do I recover the solution in terms of $x$?

Thanks.

Comment: @projectilemotion My bad, the second term is linear, not a first derivative. Now fixed.

Comment: After your edit, the change of variable is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you set $x=b t$ then $dx=b\cdot dt$ and you go from
$$ \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\pi}{b}\cdot J_1(x) \tag{1}$$
to
$$ \frac{1}{b^2}\cdot\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}+\frac{1}{b^\color{red}{3}}\cdot \frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{\pi}{b}\cdot J_1(bt). $$
$(1)$ can be solved through [Frobenius power series method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusMethod.html), or through the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform). By applying $\mathcal{L}$ to both sides of $(1)$ and setting $g(s)=\left(\mathcal{L} y\right)(s)$ we get

$$ -\left(s+\frac{1}{b^s}\right) y(0)-s y'(0) + \left(s^2+\frac{s}{b^2}\right) g(s) = -\frac{\pi}{b\sqrt{1+s^2}(s+\sqrt{1+s^2})}\tag{2} $$
hence $g(s)$ has an explicit closed form in terms of $y(0),y'(0)$ and $y$ can be recovered from $\mathcal{L}^{-1} g$.

The edited version can be tackled in the same way: the general solution to
$$ y''+\frac{1}{b^2}y=-\frac{\pi}{b}J_1(x) $$
is given by
$$ C_1 \cos\frac{x}{b}+C_2\sin\frac{x}{b}+\pi\int_{x_0}^{x}J_1(z)\sin\frac{z-x}{b}\,dz.\tag{3} $$

Comment: I am sorry - the second term in the differential equation is $b^{-2} y$, not a first derivative as I had written earlier. Can you elaborate on your Laplace transform method, please?

Comment: Thanks. Is there any hope for a closed-form solution? What is $x_{0}$ in the last equation?

Comment: @John: answer improved. I just exploited the linearity of the Laplace transform (together with the fact that the Laplace transform of $J_1$ is well-known). In a equivalent way, you may also employ the Fourier transform to instantly recognize the convolution integral now appearing in $(3)$.

Comment: @John: $C_1,C_2$ and $x_0$ depend on the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks. I understand how to find $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$, but is $x_{0}$ the point where the boundary conditions are defined?

Comment: Also, can the integral be done explicitly?

Comment: @John: yes, presumably $x_0$ is just zero. $(3)$ has not a nice closed form, but it can be numerically computed very efficiently through power series or Fourier series.